# Add icons to elements in ElementListSelectionDialog

Tags: eclipse, dialog, eclipse-rcp

I have the following code to create a dialog in a RCP Eclipse application using the `ElementListSelectionDialog` class:

```
ElementListSelectionDialog dialog = new ElementListSelectionDialog(shell, new LabelProvider());

dialog.setTitle("test");
dialog.setMessage("test");
dialog.setMultipleSelection(false);
dialog.setElements(new String[]{"test1", "test2", "test3"});
dialog.open();
```

The previous code generates this dialog:

[image]

This is fine but I also want to add icons to the elements in the list, similar to how it looks the `web.xml` editor:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the `LabelProvider` you are passing to the `ElementListSelectionDialog` constructor and override the

```
public Image getImage(Object element)
```

method. This will be called for each of the objects you add to the dialog with the `setElements` method.